# How much time is needed between measures for test-retest reliability?

Tags: reliability

I am planning a meta-analysis on reliability of various loneliness scales. We want to determine beforehand what time frame between measures we will consider.

For instance, if the time between 2 measures is 2 years (such as in some longitudinal papers), we would consider this to be an indication of rank-order stability rather than test-retest reliability. This is a clear case, but what about 3 months? Or 1 month? Where should be the limit?

We are looking for good resources to base our decision on, and would be glad with any advise.

Comment: I wonder whether you would get better answers on the psychology site as this seems to need an expertise in loneliness measurement which may be thin on the ground here.

Comment: Well it is not dependent on the loneliness measure; the same question could be asked for other self-report questionnaires.

Comment: But presumably the time interval would be different for different self-report measures depending on how labile the latent variable is.